# Remove substring from string in D

Tags: d, phobos

How to remove all occurrences of a string in another? I can do this using the following code:

```
std.array.replace: "the string".replace("the", "")
```

But I wonder if there is a dedicated function for this in phobos?

Comment: I believe it is right function, because std.string has public import for std.array.replace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It's correct function. But you might want to use it from `std.string`. Because if in future version something changes you'll still be using correct function.

From documentation of [`std.string`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html):

> The following functions are publicly imported:
>
> `std.array`: [`replace`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#replace) [`replaceInPlace`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#replaceInPlace) ...

Comment: remember too btw that replace does not work in place. So to replace the old one it is like `string changed = original.replace("thing", "else");`